# When exactly should I use a StringBuilder instead of a String

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I came across this problem with a light weight application I am developing. 
The `StringBuilder` seems to be more efficient with the memory usage.

1. why is it so?
2. where else the use of `StringBuilder` is better than a good old
   `String`?

Thank you for giving me more details

Comment: @Mureinik that's not a very good example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StringBuilder` uses less memory upon concatenation (because it doesn't copy both strings), which means that if you plan to make *many* concatenations (in a loop!) you'd better use `StringBuilder`.

Usually the comparison of performance is not done between `StringBuilder` and `String` but between `StringBuilder` and `StringBuffer`. The latter is synchronized which is "safer" but also much slower, hence again, the preference usually tends towards `StringBuilder` when you're not concerned about concurrency issues and you want optimal performance.